# Is the infinite sum of reciprocals powers of 2 a rational number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, rational-numbers

I am trying to prove that the sum $$\sum_{n \in J}^{\infty} 2^{-n}$$ is a rational number, where $J$ is some infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, but not equal $\mathbb{N}$. That is, I want to show that $1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{32} + \cdots$ is a rational number. I tried to prove by induction that every partial sum is a rational number, which seem'd okay, but I know I can't generalize to say that if all partial sums are rational, then the infinity sum is rational. So I'm stuck... and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Cf. [Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#The_existence_of_Liouville_numbers_(Liouville's_constant))

Comment: Any finite sum is rational.  Any sum which eventually includes all the numbers is rational, but one which has infinitely many included and infinitely many excluded may well not be rational.  It will be rational only if it is eventually periodic.

Comment: By the way, if $J=\Bbb N$, then the sum is rational.

Comment: or if $J=k\mathbb N$, for some $k\in\mathbb N$

Comment: Thank you all, it was illuminating!

Comment: It's excellent that you realize that induction does not allow you to jump from all finite cases (i.e. natural numbers) to an infinite case. Note that there is no way to prove that this infinite sum is rational by looking at whether the partial sums are. You must actually find the closed form for the infinite sum first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{n \in J} 2^{-n}$ is not always rational.  For example, let $J=\{0!,1!,2!,3!,4!...\}$.

$\dfrac1{2^{0!}}+\dfrac1{2^{1!}}+\dfrac1{2^{2!}}+\dfrac1{2^{3!}}+\dfrac1{2^{4!}}+...$ is a [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#The_existence_of_Liouville_numbers_(Liouville%27s_constant)),

a non-repeating decimal, and thus irrational.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just needed a counter-example, but could not find! Thank you!